# WebView - Flash overlap Issue in ICS4.0

Tags: flash, webview, overlap

**platform:** ARM7 based device
**android version:** ICS4.0
**browser:** android default browser

I am testing flash websites on android browser and observing that flash is always overlapping over webview. So if any website contains any list view/menu which falls above flash, always goes behind the flash with android browser.

Below are the suggestions which I have tried already,but no use
1. Override surfaceview add in WebView to change the zorder to false; (setZOrderOnTop(false)) 
2. Changing html page setting wmode to opaque or transparent

I have seen this working on GalaxyS2 & with Google TV image (with Chrome browser) on same platform.
In Chrome browser (GTV), WebKit rendering is done on above SurfaceView and for Flash Video's it is using PluginWindow. So WebView always remains on top of all other window. So no problem.
Interesting thing is, I have not found a single web reference which tells the possibility of rendering Webpage over SurfaceView and there is no reference about PluginWindow in android.

1. Any suggestions for above problem?
2. How to render webview over surfaceview? So that webview can be placed above all other windows

Eg: [www.coca-cola.com/en/index.html](http://www.coca-cola.com/en/index.html) & click on Coke in USA.